# Why the C++ program run slower when I use a variable to store the numeric result instead of calculating it over again?

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance

I am writing a simple C++ function to reverse an integer as follow:

```
int reverse(int x) {
    int result = 0;
    int overflow_max = INT_MAX / 10;
    int underflow_min = INT_MIN / 10;

    while (x != 0) {
        int pop = x % 10;
        if (result > overflow_max || (result == overflow_max && pop > 7)) 
            return 0;
        if (result < underflow_min  || (result == underflow_min && pop < -8)) 
            return 0;
        result *= 10;
        result += pop;
        x /= 10;
    }

    return result;
}
```

The program works fine and fast. However, when I was testing different versions of code to optimize the function, I found this version run slightly faster:

```
int reverse(int x) {
    int result = 0;

    while (x != 0) {
        int pop = x % 10;
        if (result > INT_MAX / 10 || (result == INT_MAX / 10 && pop > 7)) 
            return 0;
        if (result < INT_MIN / 10 || (result == INT_MIN / 10 && pop < -8)) 
            return 0;
        result *= 10;
        result += pop;
        x /= 10;
    }

    return result;
}
```

I don't understand the reason why the second version runs faster since it apparently repeats the calculation of INT_MAX / 10 and INT_MIN / 10, so it should have a worse performance than the first version which uses a temporary variable for storing the result to avoid repeated calculation.

Comment: Resilient measuring data and a [MCVE] please?

Comment: How are you compiling? What optimization level? Make those variables `const` and check again. `INT_MAX / 10` is a compile time constant and is not calculated at run time.

Comment: How did you measure the performance ? did you run in debug or in release mode ?

Comment: How did you profile this code?  How did you compile this code?  Where is the rest of the code... this is an incomplete snippet.

Comment: What's your compiler and optimisation setting? gcc with `-O2` generates the same code for both (it even replaces one with a jump to the other if you have both).

Comment: I measured the performance by measuring the time used by the program from start to end. The program is just a main() method calling this reverse() function with time tracking. The optimization level is `-O1`.

Comment: "I measured the performance by measuring the time" *How* did you measure the time? What *specific* time intervals did you get? "Slightly faster" is a rather meaningless quality.

Comment: I'm curious as to the details of the "how" as well, because on my machine the generated machine code was identical.  So I'd expect profiling to show them to be within statistical noise of one another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

INT_MAX is a `#define` and `10` is a constant literal, therefore, `INT_MAX/10` is a constant and, therefore, will be computed only once during compilation.

On the other hand `overflow_max` is not defined as a constant, and depending on optimization level, could incur additional memory access to read value during the loop comparison.

Comment: To add to that, `clang` produces the exact same code for both functions when `overflow_max` and `overflow_min` are const. https://godbolt.org/z/FBoJs9